# How to manage many to many relationships on a form with jsf

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf-2

So I have these tables: ocurrencia and persona, they have a many to many relationship.  This table is called identificacion. I am using hibernate.

This is the code on ocurrencia

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "identificacion", joinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_ocurrencia", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_persona", 
                nullable = false, updatable = false) })
private List<Persona> personas
```

;

This is the code on persona

```
// bi-directional many-to-one association to Identificacion
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "persona")
    private List<Ocurrencia> ocurrenciasIdentificacion;
```

I tried using  Fetchtype Lazy on Ocurrencia but I had some problems, so I used EAGER. Should I use EAGER on persona too?.  Well that is not my main concern at the moment my problem comes when I try to save ocurrencia.
So I added a selectonemenu of personas that has button that says something like "Add a Person", so if they select the persona and they hit the "Add a Person Button" it goes to ocurrencia.getPersonas().add(newPersona)
And it displays correctly on the form(before hitting save), and when I edit any of my previously recorded ocurrencias it works like a charm, but when I am creating a new Ocurrencia, I dont get an error but everythings breaks down, and it is not inserting on the database any new record.

I was loosing my mind when I tried to add a new ocurrencia without personas and it worked, it shows up on my database. So I figured that it is not able to insert anything on the table identificacion because it doesnt have the primary key from ocurrencia.

This is my GenericDao function that creates a new record of a table

```
public void crear(final T o)throws EntidadNoGrabadaException{
        try {
            em.persist(o);
        } catch (final PersistenceException e)  {
            throw new EntidadNoGrabadaException("Error al grabar: ".concat(o
                    .toString()), e);
        }
    }
```

The only solution I can think of is creating  manually a model class for identificacion, and making a many to one relationship to the ocurrencia and persona.  I think I have to add a primary key.  But this seems like a workaround solution, why do we have a many to many option if we end up doing this.

EDIT
I just found this,

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

I dont have an extra column on identificacion, is that the only way to fix this?
Thanks

UPDATE

I changed mappedby="persona" to mappedby="personas" now I am catching this error

```
23:27:20,334 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6) ec.edu.puce.biologia.excepciones.EntidadNoGrabadaException: Error al grabar: ec.edu.puce.biologia.model.Ocurrencia@22231361 persistence error org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: ec.edu.puce.biologia.model.Persona
23:27:20,335 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at ec.edu.puce.biologia.dao.impl.GenericDao.crear(GenericDao.java:68)
23:27:20,335 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-6)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
23:2
```

Comment: Your field name is `personas` but in the `mappedBy` you use `persona`, try to change it to `personas` and let me know if it will work.

Comment: That helped a little bit now I am catching errors in crear function

Comment: If you have a many to many relationship, you should be able to normalize more and create a 1 to many relationship.

Comment: @Blaine, so basically something like this http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Comment: @JuanDiego this error happen when you persist a new class attached to a class that already exists, try to use the save method... or first persist the ocurrence then add the persona and merge it.

Comment: @fmodos I understand what is happening, but I didnt understand how to fix it.  Can you elaborate a little bit more, what should I do in my crear function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because you are persisting a new object attached to an object that already exist.
Invoke the `crear` method in the `ocurrence` object before adding `personas` to the list.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed thanks to fmodos,

I added a tmpList of personas and set the list to null, then added again the list to ocurrencia and update(actualizar) my list once it was created.

```
List<Persona> tmpIdentificadores = new ArrayList<Persona>();
        if(ocurrencia.getPersonas()!=null){
            tmpIdentificadores = ocurrencia.getPersonas();
            ocurrencia.setPersonas(null);
            try {
                ocurrenciaDao.crear(ocurrencia);
            } catch (EntidadNoGrabadaException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ocurrencia.setPersonas(tmpIdentificadores);
            actualizar(ocurrencia);
        }else{
            try {
                ocurrenciaDao.crear(ocurrencia);
            } catch (EntidadNoGrabadaException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```